# Why are the mesos binaries having an "in" extension

Tags: apache-mesos

I just downloaded mesos from the apache repo. Here is the bin directory:

```
$ ll bin
total 92
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1769 Jul 17 23:14 valgrind-mesos-tests.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1769 Jul 17 23:14 valgrind-mesos-slave.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1772 Jul 17 23:14 valgrind-mesos-master.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1769 Jul 17 23:14 valgrind-mesos-local.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1026 Jul 17 23:14 mesos-tests.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack  901 Jul 17 23:14 mesos-tests-flags.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1019 Jul 17 23:14 mesos-slave.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1721 Jul 17 23:14 mesos-slave-flags.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1366 Jul 17 23:14 mesos.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1026 Jul 17 23:14 mesos-master.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack  858 Jul 17 23:14 mesos-master-flags.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1023 Jul 17 23:14 mesos-local.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack  935 Jul 17 23:14 mesos-local-flags.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1466 Jul 17 23:14 lldb-mesos-tests.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1489 Jul 17 23:14 lldb-mesos-slave.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1492 Jul 17 23:14 lldb-mesos-master.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1489 Jul 17 23:14 lldb-mesos-local.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1498 Jul 17 23:14 gdb-mesos-tests.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1527 Jul 17 23:14 gdb-mesos-slave.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1530 Jul 17 23:14 gdb-mesos-master.sh.in
-rw-r--r--.  1 stack stack 1521 Jul 17 23:14 gdb-mesos-local.sh.in
drwxr-xr-x.  2 stack stack 4096 Jul 17 23:21 .
drwxr-xr-x. 10 stack stack 4096 Jul 17 23:21 ..
```

Two things: *none* of the files are executable. Also they end with *in*  What is this about?

Comment: After download, follow the _"Building Mesos"_ instructions of [Getting Started](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/). The building process actually takes long time and it will be faster to download a packaged version. Check mesosphere's blog [here](https://mesosphere.com/blog/mesosphere-package-repositories/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those .in files have some values in them that are replaced during the build process by autotools. They are not supposed to be used directly. 
If you look into the destination directory after 'make install' you won't see any .in files there. .in is the standard extension of the files that autotools utilities process.

Answer (score -1):

First, file extensions in *nix systems don't matter. There are some conventions that are followed by most, but they're merely conventions - that's it.

Second, if you'd looked at the files, you'd realize they're just bash scripts. You can either run them like you'd run any other shell script: `$ bash /path/to/script`.

If you prefer, use `chmod` to add the executable bit and then you can run them directly.

Comment: I am aware of all you said.  Simply changing the bits to ugo+x does not fix the issue. The scripts themselves invoke other siblings and expect  <foo>.sh: their scripts are not looking for <foo>.sh.in.  In addition This was a tarball so the file permissions are included. The fact they are not correct indicates a problem.

Comment: Fair enough. If you think there is an issue with mesos packaging, you should contact the mesos devs. This type of query isn't really on-topic here.